# Add custom ILogger to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have a central Project which generates all the Loggers for the subprojects. (And does a lot of other stuff which is not nessesary for my problem)

One of the Subprojects is an ASP.NET Web API. Now I want to add the Logger which is generated by a Logger Factory (see below) to the WebApplication. The problem is that the current version of WebApplication doesn't accept ILoggers...

(I use .Net 6)

The following function generates my Logger Factory:

```
private ILoggerFactory CreateLoggerFactory()
{
    IConfiguration configSerilog = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
        .Build();
    
    Serilog.Core.Logger serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configSerilog)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("ComponentShortcuts", _componentShortcuts)
        .CreateLogger();
    
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
        .AddSerilog(serilogLogger);
    return loggerFactory;
}
```

The only thing I can do at the moment is to delete the default Loggers:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add my Logger, because there is no `AddLogger()` function.
(I have no idea how to convert the ILogger or if there is something else that I can generate with the Logger Factory that helps me.)

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

So I faced this same issue 2 days ago with logging in .net 6 web api. And I found a solution to it that worked for me, i-e; By using LoggerConfiguration.
Although I'm still looking for a way to do it by LoggerFactory I'll post it as soon as I figure it out. Till then I hope this helps you.

Here's my code;

Program.cs

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            //.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
            //.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore",LogEventLevel.Error)
            //.MinimumLevel.Override("Serilog", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithClientIp("CF-Connecting-IP")
            .Enrich.WithClientAgent()
            .CreateLogger();

Log.Logger = logger;
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```

Then add the middleware

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

appsettings.json (I'm logging to Console and Sql Server also (In case you want to do it.))

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning",
    "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
  }
},
"Enrich": [
  "FromLogContext",
  "WithMachineName",
  "WithClientIp",
  "WithClientAgent",
  {
    "Name": "WithClientIp",
    "Args": {
      "xForwardHeaderName": "CF-Connecting-IP"
    }
  }
],
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "MSSqlServer",
    "Args": {
      "connectionString": "",
      "sinkOptionsSection": {
        "tableName": "TableName",
        "autoCreateSqlTable": true
      },
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "columnOptionsSection": {
        "primaryKeyColumnName": "",
        "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent", "SourceContext" ],
        "additionalColumns": [
          {
            "ColumnName": "ClientIPAddress",
            "PropertyName": "UserIp",
            "DataType": "nvarchar"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
}
```

Feel free to let me know if you have any doubts. And don't forget to install the relevant nuget packages.

[image]

All the best!! :)